# Using Rcpp headers in C++

Tags: c++, r, header-files, rcpp

I'm an R programmer trying to learn C++ because I've seen the vast improvements you can make to code using C++ code within R.  I'm trying to play around with the Rcpp library, and I've gotten examples to work in R.  However, I'd like to write some C++ code in my C++ editor and use some of the classes from Rcpp (just to get a better understanding of how to use the package).  I tried to compile the following code in my C++ editor (CodeBlocks):

```
include </path_to_R/R/win-library/2.15/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h>
```

but then it fails because it can't find  from the first few lines of :

```
%...
#ifndef Rcpp_hpp
#define Rcpp_hpp

/* it is important that this comes first */
#include <RcppCommon.h>
...
```

Is there a better way to include all the Rcpp code?  Do I need to go through the Rcpp.h file and replace all the file names with their paths?

I realize this is a newby question, and I'm sorry...  I'm sure the answers out in the documentation somewhere, but I don't know how to even look for it.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to add the `<RcppPath>/inst/include` to the search path explicitly, e.g. `-I<RcppPath>/inst/include`. After that you can just `#include <Rcpp.h>`. Not sure how this is done within Code::blocks though. Note that you'll have to add the `R` headers and libraries as well. Try making a package, looking at what `R CMD INSTALL` does, and mimicing the compilation in your editor.

Comment: @KevinUshey you should promote your comment as an answer.

Comment: @RomainFrancois I agree, I'd accept it :)

Answer (score 3):

You could, and maybe should, look at the [Rinside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) package which embeds R into C++ -- so C++ is the `main()` here and the Makefile snippets will give you an idea.

People have used Rinside with different IDEs and there are contributed files for use with Eclipse etc pp.  Try those, and if you need more help then try the rcpp-devel list as the author of those contributed files may not read posts here.

Answer (score 2):

Although, of course, Code::Blocks is not eclipse, you might find [this guide](http://blog.fellstat.com/?p=170) informative at to what it takes to get an IDE to play nicely with R and Rcpp.

If you are able and willing, it would be useful if you documented similar steps as to how you got Code::Blocks to work alongside R / Rcpp.